# Как отправлять письма с сайта на node.js, расположенном на Digital Ocean?

Tags: node.js, email, sendmail

Есть сайт на node.js + express на Digital Ocean. Допустим, мне нужно сделать форму обратной связи. Стоит ли использовать сторонние сервисы, позволяющие отправлять почту через api(mailgun, Mandrill и т. д.)? Или же лучше использовать nodemailer? В последнем случае, нужно ли поднимать на Digital Ocean параллельно второй сервер для почты? Где можно почитать о том, как организовать такой функционал?

Mikhail Vaysman, спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ

Answer (score 1):

Самый просто вариант - это использовать сторонний сервис. Это так же позволит получить некоторую дополнительную информацию (не для всех сервисов) - процент доставки писем и пр.

Так же можно установить MTA (mail transfer agent) на свой сервер и использовать его, но это значительно сложнее и требует знаний. Если объем писем не большой, то разворачивать отдельный сервер не обязательно - все можно поставить на один.

Как установить свой MTA подробно описано в руководствах на Digital Ocean. Вот несколько примеров:

- [How To Install the Send-Only Mail Server "Exim" on Ubuntu 12.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-send-only-mail-server-exim-on-ubuntu-12-04)
- [How To Install and Configure Postfix on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- [How to Install and Configure Postfix as a Send-Only SMTP Server on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04)